# Saxon .Net transformation

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, saxon

Maybe this is a dumb question but I'm a totally newbie when it comes to XSL.

I'm using this command line to perform a transformation which works great:

```
transform.exe -s: source.xml -xsl:rules.xsl -o: output.xml -xi:on
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result from c# but the output file is empty. What is the equivalent of the "-xi" parameter?

Thanks.

```
  Uri xslUri = new Uri(@"rules.xsl");
  Uri inputUri = new Uri(@"source.xml");
  Uri outputUri = new Uri(@"toc.hhc");

  // Compile stylesheet
  try
  {
    Processor processor = new Processor();
    XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(inputUri);
    XsltCompiler compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
    XsltExecutable exec = compiler.Compile(xslUri);
    XsltTransformer transformer = exec.Load();
    transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

    // Create a serializer
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputUri.AbsolutePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    serializer.SetOutputStream( fs );

    // Transform the source XML to System.out.
    transformer.Run( serializer );
  }
  catch( Exception e )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
  }
```

Comment: The documentation http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/XInclude.html says that "On the .NET platform, there is a customized XmlReader that performs XInclude processing available at http://www.xmlmvp.org/xinclude/index.html. You can supply this as an argument to the method Build(XmlReader parser) in the DocumentBuilder class of the .NET Saxon API.". However that xmlmvp.org has long vanished. I am not sure which other options there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to set `proc.Implementation.setXIncludeAware(true);` but it did not work for me with Saxon 9.6.0.7. Therefore I posted my result at https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/6206 and Saxonica created the bug report https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2488 which was fixed later on. So it seems you have to wait until the fix is included in a new release to be able to use XInclude in a .NET application.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to test it to be 100% sure that it works, but I think you should be able to do

```
processor.setProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/xinclude-aware", "true")
```